# Почему вызывается исключение на функции min_elem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

```
class Matrix
{
    int n;
    int m;
    int** matr;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int, int);
    
    int min_elem();
    int max_elem();
};
int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    Matrix();
    Matrix m1(10, 4);
    m1.min_elem();
    cout << m1.min_elem();
    
}
Matrix::Matrix()
{

}
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m)
{
    int** matr = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << " " << matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    this->n = n;
    this->m = m;
}
int Matrix::min_elem()
{
    int max = matr[0][0];  //здесь вызывается исключение
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (matr[i][j] > max)
                max = matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассмотрим ваш

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m)
{
    int** matr = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << " " << matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    this->n = n;
    this->m = m;
}
```

Вы старательно выделили память - но не для члена `matr`, а для **локальной переменной**. А в `min_elem()` обратились к неинициализированному члену класса `matr`...

Или допишите в конце конструктора строчку

```
this->matr = matr;
```

или уберите `int**` перед `matr` в функции.